# ASP.NET MVC4 authorization depending on role and information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application which have 3 roles: admin, manager and editor. The editors can CRUD articles in the system BUT the editors can only read, update or delete their OWN articles. I've seen I can control the access to the controller and action by adding:

```
[Authorize(Roles="editor")]
```

but it only restricts the role not the information.

If the editor A created the article 1 ONLY the editor A has access to that article.
No other role has access to the controller or the information.
What would be the best practice in order to restrict the access by role and by context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this in the core of your system, for example by having a field in your datastore, identifying creator and users with permission.

Then you could implement your own authorizeattribute like;

public class CustomAuthenticateAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // your own business logic, for instance, check if the user is the 
    // creator of the requested resource (check a database field you 
    // have created to identify the creator etc...)
    // if that goes well authorize using regular roles, below

    return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}
```

}

You would then decorate your controller with

```
[AuthorizeAttribute(Role = "editors")]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not practical to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to check whether a user is allowed to update a specific article.

Instead, you want to check that logic in controller (or business logic). You can see that approach in a lot of open source projects.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles="editor")]    
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(ArticleModel model)
{
   if(IsUserAllowedToUpdate(userId, model.ArticleId))
   {
      // Update article
   }
  return View(model);
}
```